# What does this transaction mean?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

First things first, I'm a newbie in everything related to bitcoins.

I'm analyzing a few tens of addresses checking which ones have received payments, and one of them is the following: https://blockchain.info/address/121orLQW2LanEtso2htwZSfZ3vV4toLKt6. I'm not sure about what I'm seeing.

I understand that the owner of the wallet `121orLQW2LanEtso2htwZSfZ3vV4toLKt6` received a payment of 0.0001 BTC from two different people, the owner of `1E9b2CvbB9pKT617zNbxoVNH65XqMjarPX` and the owner of `1JXstXTaeg6eH3wCXvdC7TYSA8ntWAsPc8`. But if this was the case (I think it's not), why are both payments grouped on the same transaction?

Also, if I click to enable advanced view at the bottom of the page, I see that the first paid 0.0001 and the second 0.00010782, however the overall income was 0.0001 instead of 0.0002+.

Basically, what I'm asking is if you can explain me the transaction on that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner of `1E9b2CvbB9pKT617zNbxoVNH65XqMjarPX` is likely the same person as the owner of `1JXstXTaeg6eH3wCXvdC7TYSA8ntWAsPc8`. A single user can have as many addresses as they want. When the sender wished to send .0001 BTC to `121orLQW2LanEtso2htwZSfZ3vV4toLKt6`, two of their addresses were emptied to meet the required amount.

The inputs sum up to .00020782, but only .0001 is sent to `121orLQW2LanEtso2htwZSfZ3vV4toLKt6`. The remaining .00010782 was used as a miner's fee, and went to the miner who mined the block this transaction is included in.